# Questions About The JavaFX Canvas

Tags: java, javafx, buffer, port

I have been writing a game in Java2D with Canvas for a while, And want to port it to JavaFX. I took a look at the JavaFX Canvas, And i have a few questions about it:

1. Currently, I have the game running on a separate thread from the application. The thread updates and renders the game. But with the JavaFX canvas, You cant draw to it unless it is on the JavaFX Application Thread.  Do you know of any ways to get around this?
2. The Java2D Canvas has a BufferStratagy that can be used for triple buffering. But the JavaFX Canvas only has a built in double buffer. I am guessing it would be possible to write a triple buffer manually (I know how to do it with a double buffer). Can you explain how i could do this?
3. Would it be best just to stick with java2D instead of switching to JavaFX?

Thanks for your help. :)

Comment: Your first point is actually true for Swing as well.  But I assume you are using a `BufferStrategy`...if you're not, you're breaking some serious rules.  JavaFX just forces this rule and no, you can't get around it. Your second point is, yes, like you would any buffering strategy, create a series of `Image`s and cycle through them, the real trick is making sure that the buffer been painted is not the buffer you are rendering to. You third point promotes personal opinion and would best removed.  Your choice to use a framework should be based on your needs, not someone elses opinion...IMHO ;)

Comment: If you want to port to JavaFX (and I'm also going to avoid posting an opinion), you might want to see if there are other (perhaps better) ways than using the JavaFX canvas, e.g. just manipulating the properties of a bunch of Nodes (Shapes, etc) added to a Pane. [Steven van Impe has an example](http://asipofjava.blogspot.be/2014/05/game-loops-and-applying-them-to-javafx.html) (the link is to part 2, read part 1 first).